# What CSS do you use to style a table CELL?

Tags: css, html-table

I want to make increase **cell padding** via CSS (so I don't have to set *each* table on the page).

I can't see how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

is the element for a cell within a row.

So:

```
 td { 
 padding:10px;}
```